# How to allow modal to close itself in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal window for my basic, one-page React app. I've constructed the modal component like so:

```
class Modal extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Modal">
                <button
                    className="Modal-close"
                    onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
                    ✖
                </button>
                <div
                    className="Modal-contentContainer"
                    onKeyDown={e => {
                        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                            this.props.closeModal();
                        }
                    }
                }>
                    {this.props.content}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see, the specific content of the modal is passed through the content prop. However, I want to be able to have the modal itself call closeModal at the end of the specific process in the authentication modal, and I can't figure out how to do that. Is there a simple way to add the function to the content prop? Or is there a wholly different way I should be creating modals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `React.cloneElement` to pass additional properties to `content` element:

```
class Modal extends Component {
  render() {

    const extendedContent = React.cloneElement(this.props.content, {
       closeModal: this.props.closeModal
    });

    return (
        <div className="Modal">
            <button
                className="Modal-close"
                onClick={this.props.closeModal}>
                ✖
            </button>
            <div
                className="Modal-contentContainer"
                onKeyDown={e => {
                    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
                        this.props.closeModal();
                    }
                }
            }>
                {extendedContent}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted; I'd been trying to use Object.assign but react blocks that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)